# HTML Divs are inconsistently using the CSS file

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I am using a framework called 960.gs (which is great!)

I build a div class 12 (which expands across whole web page)
I then decide to build three divs within the class 12, each div has class 4 (4+4+4=12)

I have 2 CSS files, one text which has default settings for body, general fonts etc (general settings). And the other CSS file - stylesheet which is where I edit each div and apply styles etc.

For some reason, the 3 divs (within the main class 12 div). The first and second div utilize the text.css sheet, and the third div uses the stylesheet.css.

I have checked spelling and everything but I don't know why it's behaving like this. Advice would be helpful!

I have 5 screen shots of the code, advice would be appreciated https://db.tt/vyv5ihq4

Comment: `#siteonlineleft, #siteonlinemiddle, #siteonlineright p` ← See anything wrong here?

Comment: @kei I didn't realise I had to put p after each individual grid... you might be on to something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nesting the three columns inside the `.grid_12` container, just use `.grid_4` for each of those columns. After the last .`grid_4`, use `div.clear` to setup a new row for additional content (`div.clear` should be used after each row so floats are reset and/or do not overlap one another).

```
<div class="grid_4">
  Grid one
</div>
<div class="grid_4">
  Grid two
</div>
<div class="grid_4">
  Grid three
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- new columns and content go here after the clearfix above -->
```

**[960.gs demo](http://960.gs/demo.html)**

Comment: I'll try this now and I'll report back to you with my results!

Comment: together you seem to have resolved the issue. So should you always use the div.clear over nesting grids inside one another (alpha/omega)?

Comment: The example above isn't the always or never solution. For example, say you have a main container `.grid_8` and a sidebar `.grid_4`. If you wanted to add additional columns inside `.grid_8`, you'd have to use `.alpha` on the left most column, and `.omega` on the last column in that row. Once you've hit the last column in the row, you'll need to `.clear` those floated items.

So in a nutshell, anytime you are done with a row of columns, you should clear them with `div.clear`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes much more sense now! I will make sure to incorporate div.clear from now on!